# Book about people with telepathy

Tags: story-identification, novel

I remember reading a book, and the "hero" discovered he had the power of telepathy, and then found a woman that also had this power. Before realizing there were many other hidden with the same powers, I thought it was called the **Invisibles** or something similar?

Book was out in UK. Was Set in USA late 70s early 80s. Bloke took a load of drugs which "opened" his mind, I think the girl a "psychic", but was actually using telepathy. Turned out the Russians and the usa both had active users. read it 40 years ago (1970s) that about all I can remember.

Does anyone know what this is?

Comment: When did you read it? In what country? Do you remember anything else at all -- this description is probably too vague to be useful?

Comment: Book was out in UK. Was Set in USA late 70s early 80s. Bloke took a load of drugs which "opened" his mind, I think the girl a "psychic", but was actually using telepathy. Turned out the Russians and the usa both had active users. read it 40 years ago that about all I can remember.

Comment: http://scifi.wikia.com/wiki/Drug_References_in_Science_Fiction

Comment: looked at the scifi-wiki thanks for the link, didn't see the book though.

Answer (score 4):

The "load of drugs" is from *Pstalemate* by Lester Del Rey (Published 1971).  The protagonist finds he's telepathic, then learns that every known telepath, ever, has gone completely stark raving mad.  He takes hallucinogens repeatedly, trying to induce the worst "bad trip" he can, to steel himself against the madness that will come when he can no longer shield his mind against the world -- only to discover, in the end, that he's also precognitive (reading his own future mind), and was simply "seeing" those bad trips in his flashes of future madness.

Comment: *Pstalemate* also appears to include a phony "psychic" (but actually telepathic) woman, based on [this review](http://www.chris-winter.com/Erudition/Reviews/SciFiFic/DelRey_L/Pstalemate.html), "But then he notices a fortune-teller at another party's table. [...] Soon the woman, heavily made up and costumed as a gypsy, sits down at his table."

Comment: Thanks, @apsillers, it's been a long time since I last read the book.

Comment: Thanks for this, looks good, not the book I was looking for, but I will grab a copy and give it a read. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

**The Invisibles** by *Bernhardt J. Hurwood*, fits the description.The book was first published in 1971 in the U.S. The hero overdoses on a psychedelic drug and finds he can astral project and has telepathic ability. It has him meeting a woman who has similar abilities. I believe it had the U.S and Soviet users. It was followed up by The Mind Masters.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Could this be The Impossibles by Randal Garrett and Laurence M. Janifer under the pen-name of "Mark Phillips"

It's part of a trilogy - I've only read the first one (Brain Twister) and my memory of it is a bit sketchy, but it's about the right period and has competing cold war spy organisations of psychics. Sorry I've not got time to look up further details, hope this is enough to Google it to check it out...

Comment: Further details on the [Mark Phillips Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Phillips_(author)). Even better, the "psi-power" series (of which *The Impossibles* is book #2) is in the public domain in the U.S. -- links to the Project Gutenberg pages are under "Texts online" in the Wikipedia page (book #1, *Brain Twister* is [here](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/22332)).

Comment: Many thanks for the link, its not the one I was looking for, but it does look like a good read though. Cheers.

Comment: Generally "I think it's this, go google" is a poor answer for SE sites.